# Can't inline-block two span

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I've been trying to put this two span classes next to each other without any good result.

Maybe is there any other way that I'm missing?

Thank you in advance.

```css
.numbered {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #c61274;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.titled {
  color: #444949;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: inline-block;
  /* to make it inline */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="badge numbered">1</span><span class="titled">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, aliquam, ducimus, ullam unde expedita ex sapiente maxime deleniti eaque nesciunt placeat alias nostrum itaque voluptates ipsum odio sequi cum reiciendis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="badge numbered">2</span><span class="titled">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, aliquam, ducimus, ullam unde expedita ex sapiente maxime deleniti eaque nesciunt placeat alias nostrum itaque voluptates ipsum odio sequi cum reiciendis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="badge numbered">3</span><span class="titled">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, aliquam, ducimus, ullam unde expedita ex sapiente maxime deleniti eaque nesciunt placeat alias nostrum itaque voluptates ipsum odio sequi cum reiciendis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDXIQ.png)

Comment: I don't think you need display inline-block for `.titled`. That is what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.titled` span was already `inline`..there is no need to set it to `inline-block` and the top margin on the `.numbered` span is also unnecessary.

```
.numbered {
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        background-color: #c61274;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-size: 17px;
        padding-top: 13px;
        margin: 4px;
}

.titled {
    color: #444949;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GqbgEQ)

```css
.badge.numbered {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #c61274;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  margin: 4px;
}
.titled {
  color: #444949;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="badge numbered">1</span><span class="titled">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, aliquam, ducimus, ullam unde expedita ex sapiente maxime deleniti eaque nesciunt placeat alias nostrum itaque voluptates ipsum odio sequi cum reiciendis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="badge numbered">2</span><span class="titled">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, aliquam, ducimus, ullam unde expedita ex sapiente maxime deleniti eaque nesciunt placeat alias nostrum itaque voluptates ipsum odio sequi cum reiciendis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <span class="badge numbered">3</span><span class="titled">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, aliquam, ducimus, ullam unde expedita ex sapiente maxime deleniti eaque nesciunt placeat alias nostrum itaque voluptates ipsum odio sequi cum reiciendis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```